# Pandas change column values from dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following to tables of boolean values:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': [True, False, False], 
                         'b': [False, True, False]},
                         index=pd.Series([1, 2, 3], name='index'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'w': [True, False, False], 
                         'x': [False, True, False],
                         'y': [True, True, True],
                         'z': [True, False, True]},
                         index=pd.Series([1, 2, 3], name='index'))
```

| index | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | True | False |
| 2 | False | True |
| 3 | False | False |

| index | w | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | True | False | True | True |
| 2 | False | True | True | False |
| 3 | False | False | True | True |

and the following dictionary:

```
dic = {'a': ['w', 'x'], 'b': ['y', 'z']}
```

I want to update `df2` so that if a column in `df1` is True, the column names that correspond to that column in `dic` are flagged as False.
For example, since column `a` is True for index 1, columns `w` and `w` for index 1 should be turned to False.

The resulting table should look like this:

| index | w | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **False** | False | True | True |
| 2 | False | True | **False** | False |
| 3 | False | False | True | True |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have `True`/`False` and only need to change `True` to `False`, this simple loop with masking should work for you:

*NB. I am calling the dictionary `dic` as `dict` the python builtin to construct dictionaries*

```
for k,v in dic.items():
    df2[v] = df2[v].mask(df1[k], False)
```

output:

```
           w      x      y      z
index                            
1      False  False   True   True
2      False   True  False  False
3      False  False   True   True
```

Answer (score 0):

We can reverse the key:value association in the dictionary to [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) `df2` so that the columns align with the names in `df1`. Then, use [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html), to update values (aligned on columns) and [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) to restore the column names:

```
# Avoiding using `dict` as a variable name
d = {'a': ['w', 'x'], 'b': ['y', 'z']}
df2 = (
    df2.rename(columns={v: k for k, lst in d.items() for v in lst})
        .mask(df1, False)
        .set_axis(df2.columns, axis=1)
)
```

`df2`:

```
           w      x      y      z
index                            
1      False  False   True   True
2      False   True  False  False
3      False  False   True   True
```